# Reboot and select proper boot device Error

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd, clone

In the morning I was using my desktop without any issues. I left my apartment for about 2 hours, returned back home to find the my mouse and screen frozen.

I restart my computer and get the error: "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key"

Here is everything I've tried so far...

1. Changed the boot order in my BIOS. Windows 10 is installed in my m.2 NVME and is where I have most of my documents/files saved, but I have a SATA SSD as well which is empty. Nothing happened
2. I took apart my desktop and put it back together, let everything discharge and unplugged for an hour, still get the same error
3. I took it to microcenter, they ran some diagnostics without any conclusive results and told me to replace my m.2 NVME. I asked them to test using one of the m.2 NVME's with windows 10 loaded to test my computer, no issue, they tested my m.2 NVME in one of their desktop computers and was able to load windows 10 without any issues? They also said they were able to see all my files and documents were there. I corroborated the same result when I downloaded Windows 10 media creation onto a USB and was able to see my saved files in through the repair Windows function.
4. After microcenter, I bought a m.2 NVME enclosure for my unbootable m.2 NVME so that I could plug this in as a USB to see all my files and programs (this worked!) and I bought a new m.2 NVME and installed windows to my desktop. I was able to load into Windows 10 no issue, just missing everything from my old m.2 NVME SSD.

Now my question is... if I clone (I've never cloned any drives before) my unbootable m.2 NVME using cloning software such as Macrium Reflect or Clonezilla onto my new m.2 NVME, will my new m.2 NVME be unbootable as well?

Is there anyway to reinstall windows on my unbootable m.2 NVME without disturbing/deleting my documents/files?

Thank you for your help